Add a caption and a source to image, keeping caption centered and source alligned to image to left
I have a rather obnoxious thesis guideline to follow, and unfortunately I've been unable to meet it with my LATEX skills.
I need to center the caption of a figure, and this caption can possibly be a multiline text. I also need to add a source, but the source must come over the caption. The real hard part for me has been to meet the rule that the source must be alligned to the image, on the left (not to the margin of the page).
Additionally, if it isn't too much hassle, the vertical spacing between the source and caption should be 6pt (MS Word units).
The code below is my attempt to follow the guidelines. The second image is simply to check that the caption numbering is consistent.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
    
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Source: {#2}}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=original}
    \caption{ {#1} }
} %


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{eta-carinae.jpg}
        \captionsource{Caption text of the image, with more than one line of text, centered, I'll just be filling with text until it overflows to next line.}{A source with ref, cite or free text.}
        \label{Source with cite.}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{crab-nebula.jpg}
    \captionsource{Caption text of the image, with more than one line of text, centered, I'll just be filling with text until it overflows to next line.}{A source with ref, cite or free text.}
    \label{Source with cite.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

% Image sources:    
% Eta Carinae https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_Carinae#/media/Ficheiro:EtaCarinae.jpg
% Crab Nebula:  
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Crab_Nebula.jpg

This is the desired output:


Welcome to TeX.SX!

If the source caption wider than the figure, where it should be aligned? Or I should ask that is the source caption always same width according to the figure.

Thank you @jlab, honored to be in the presence of the wizards of TeX. In response to your question Tom, the source caption allignment isn't really specified in this particular case, so a left justification is perfectly acceptable. In practice, most source texts I've used have been smaller than the figure width.

I assume that the source caption is always same width as the figure and left aligned. I rather don't use two \caption commands, it will mass up your list of figures. Here is solution to put figure and source in a \parbox with same width as the figure.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[justification=centering,skip=6pt]{caption}

\newcommand{\graphicsandsource}[2]{%
\sbox0{#1}\parbox{\wd0}{#1\par Source: #2}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering\graphicsandsource{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}{A source with ref, cite or free text.} 
        \caption{Caption text of the image, with more than one line of text, centered, I'll just be filling with text until it overflows to next line.}
        \label{Source with cite1.}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering\graphicsandsource{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}}{A source with ref, cite or free text.} 
    \caption{Caption text of the image, with more than one line of text, centered, I'll just be filling with text until it overflows to next line.}
    \label{Source with cite2.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


